# How to convert decimal to date?

Tags: sql, date, decimal, valueconverter

I have a problem. I have a field START_VALUE where the data type is decimal. I want to convert Decimal to Date.

The data type START_VALUE is Decimal.The data of START_VALUE  is :

`START_VALUE
|=========|
| 240368 |
| 198448 |
| 197396 |
| 126743 |`

I want to convert to Datetime and what i want to expect is like 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000'

I don't know if the value is Julian date or else. Please help me to find the right select query.
Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using? What is the type of the column? What date do you expect for the values you posted in your question? Without that it could be anything.. for example do you want "24 March 1968" for the first row?

Comment: Use `from_unixtime(START_VALUE) as mydate` if you are using mysql.

Comment: I use SQL server database, source type of the column is decimal and i want convert to date. and the value that i expect is like 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000'. because i want migration from SSIS to datastage.

Comment: sorry.. i must try in oracle, not sql server. my fault. Please help me.

Comment: This is almost certainly not Unix time. However, if you don't know what the base-line date for this number is, or how it's constructed, I'm unsure how you can expect others to help. You need to talk to the person responsible for the data/database.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this

```
CREATE FUNCTION Number_To_Date(No_Of_Days NUMBER)
RETURN DATE IS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_date('1899-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + No_Of_Days;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query in SQL Server to parse it to datetime

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CAST(START_VALUE
 as varchar(8)),1,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(START_VALUE
 as varchar(8)),3,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(START_VALUE
 as varchar(8)),5,2),5) AS DateTimeValue

FROM Table
```

If you are using Oracle then you can use the following query

```
SELECT TO_DATE(CAST(START_VALUE AS VARCHAR(8), 'DDMMYY') FROM Table
```

Comment: what if i try in oracle?

Comment: but the result is so weird. i have value '240368' and if i use that query, and then i get result is not what i expect. 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000'

Comment: It works in SQL Server. What result are you getting?

Comment: sorry.. i must try the query in oracle, not sql server. my fault. Please help me

Comment: Can you check the new query. I do not have oracle environment to test.